# App crashing unknowingly in remote device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have uploaded an app to app store. It is working perfectly in all other countries but not working in Ireland. It is crashing simultaneously in all the screens. I have attached the crash log from the app. I couldn't able to find where and what reason it is crashing. Please help me to find out.

[Link for the crash log below](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lYzVH_h0vQaFRIY0RuQjMwWG8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to symbolize the Crash Log

Comment: The log can’t be reached verify your link please

Comment: Try `Simulate Location` in Xcode and put it to Ireland or where ever you want and check the app for crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug with simulating location, application region and application language:

Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options Tab.

[image]

For location simulation you will need to generate gpx file. You can do it with some online tool like [this](http://gpx-poi.com) or [this](https://gpxgenerator.com). Check out [this tutorial](https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the simulated location for ireland and found the issue where it is crashing.